# Multidimensional array update

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I am trying to update each language as a multidimensional array to another multidimensional array but it seems to be only saving the last key e.g.(lang_3) but not lang_1 & lang_2. Cracking my head to figure this out. Hope someone can point out my faults. ($country_specs = list of language, $get_code = country code)

```
    $awards = array(
        'award_year'           => sanitize_array_text_field($_POST['award_year']),
        'award_title_user'      => sanitize_array_text_field($_POST['award_title_user']),
        'award_description_user'   => sanitize_array_text_field($_POST['award_description_user'])
        );

    foreach ($country_specs as $specs => $value) { 
    if ($value[0] == $get_code ) {
        foreach ($value['lang'] as $lang_key => $lang) {

            $awards_title = 'award_title_'.$lang_key;
            $awards_description = 'award_description_'.$lang_key;

            $awards_lang = array(
                $awards_title       => sanitize_array_text_field($_POST[$awards_title]),
                $awards_description   => sanitize_array_text_field($_POST[$awards_description])
                );

            update_user_meta($user_id, 'awards', array_merge($awards,$awards_lang));
                }
            }
        }
```

Current code output example:

> Array ( 
>           [award_year] => Array ( 
>                               [0] => 1999-01 
>                               [1] => 2010-02 ) 
>           [award_title_user] => Array ( 
>                               [0] => 2 
>                               [1] => tt ) 
>           [award_description_user] => Array ( 
>                               [0] => 2 
>                               [1] => ddd ) 
>           [award_title_lang3] => Array ( 
>                               [0] => 2CC 
>                               [1] => zz ) 
>           [award_description_lang3] => Array ( 
>                               [0] => 2CCCCCCC 
>                               [1] => dzz ) )

Comment: maybe add a line like this `$awards = array_merge($awards,$awards_lang);` to save the change and then move `update_user_meta` out of the loops and make it `update_user_meta($user_id, 'awards', $awards);`

Comment: @UnLoCo Just tried that, it didnt work. The output is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Working code as follows.

> ```
>   $awards = array(
>         'award_year'           => sanitize_array_text_field($_POST['award_year']),
>         'award_title_user'      => sanitize_array_text_field($_POST['award_title_user']),
>         'award_description_user'   => sanitize_array_text_field($_POST['award_description_user'])
>         );
>     $awards_new_lang = array();
>     foreach ($country_specs as $specs => $value) { 
>     if ($value[0] == $get_code ) {
>         foreach ($value['lang'] as $lang_key => $lang) {
>             $awards_title = 'award_title_'.$lang_key;
>             $awards_description = 'award_description_'.$lang_key;
>             $awards_new_lang[$awards_title]         = sanitize_array_text_field($_POST[$awards_title]);
>             $awards_new_lang[$awards_description]   = sanitize_array_text_field($_POST[$awards_description]);
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         $array_merge_new = array_merge($awards, $awards_new_lang);
>     update_user_meta($user_id, 'awards', $array_merge_new);
> ```

I created a new array ($awards_new_lang) and did an array merge with the old array, thus combining both of the arrays together.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it outputs as expected, I tried the mimic the variables structures

```
<?php
$awards = array(
    'award_year'           => '1999',
    'award_title_user'      => '2',
    'award_description_user'   => '2CCCCCCC'
);

$value = array();
$value['lang'] = array(1, 2, 3);

foreach ($value['lang'] as $lang_key) {

    $awards_title = 'award_title_'.$lang_key;
    $awards_description = 'award_description_'.$lang_key;

    $awards_lang = array(
        $awards_title       => "$lang_key title",
        $awards_description   => "$lang_key desc"
    );
    //array merge returns an array, we save the changes here to use them later when the loops are through
    $awards = array_merge($awards,$awards_lang);
}
echo '<pre>';
//Final updated version of the array
var_dump($awards);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Outputs:

```
array(9) {
  ["award_year"]=>
  string(4) "1999"
  ["award_title_user"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["award_description_user"]=>
  string(8) "2CCCCCCC"
  ["award_title_1"]=>
  string(7) "1 title"
  ["award_description_1"]=>
  string(6) "1 desc"
  ["award_title_2"]=>
  string(7) "2 title"
  ["award_description_2"]=>
  string(6) "2 desc"
  ["award_title_3"]=>
  string(7) "3 title"
  ["award_description_3"]=>
  string(6) "3 desc"
}
```

Comment: I just tried the code but i am still getting the same output (only the last key). The $_POST field is an array as well e.g.(name="award_description_".$lang_key."[]"). I think that could be the reason.

Comment: it should be [award_description_lang3] => Array ( [0] => 2CCCCCCC [1] => dzz )